# Uncaught Error: Class 'Instamojo\Exception\InstamojoException' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, composer-php, instamojo

```
     $authType = "app/user";
     $api = Instamojo\Instamojo::init($authType,[
     "client_id" =>  'XXXXXQAZ',
     "client_secret" => 'XXXXQWE',
     ],true);
     try {
     $response = $api->createPaymentRequest(array(
        "purpose" => "FIFA 16",
        "amount" => $_POST["amount"],
        "buyer_name" => $_POST["name"],
        "send_email" => true,
        "email" => $_POST["email"],
        "phone" => $_POST["phone"],
        "redirect_url" =>"http://localhost/instamojo/payment-                                   success.php"
        ));
        var_dump($response);
         }
         catch (Exception $e) {
         print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
          };
```

I am trying to integrate instamojo in my project for transaction purpose but getting this error.
tried a lot but was not able to solve this issue. help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I update the composer and also removed the `throw new InvalidRequestException` from `final class Instamojo` and the issue still persist.

And this is part the which is causing issue this file comes with when a downloaded instamojo through composer

```
    private static function validateTypeParams($type, $params)
{
    if (!in_array(strtolower($type), Instamojo::VALID_TYPES)) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException('Invalid init type');
    }

    if (empty($params['client_id'])) {
        throw new MissingParameterException('Client Id is missing');
    }

    if (empty($params['client_secret'])) {
        throw new MissingParameterException('Client Secret is missing');
    }

    if (strtolower($type) == 'user') {
        if (empty($params['username'])) {
            throw new MissingParameterException('Username is missing');
        }

        if (empty($params['password'])) {
            throw new MissingParameterException('Password is missing');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this problem really related to Composer?

Answer (score 0):

change code for class InvalidRequestException

```
<?php

namespace Instamojo\Exception;

use Exception;

class InstamojoException extends Exception {
    private $httpErrorCode;
    private $errorNumber;
    private $errorMessage;
    
    public function __construct($httpErrorCode, $errorNumber, $errorMessage) {
        parent::__construct ($errorMessage);

        $this->httpErrorCode = $httpErrorCode;
        $this->errorNumber   = $errorNumber;
        $this->errorMessage  = $errorMessage;
    }

    public function getHttpErrorCode() {
        return $this->httpErrorCode;
    }
    
    public function getErrorNumber() {
        return $this->errorNumber;
    }
    
    public function getErrorMessage() {
        return $this->errorMessage;
    }
}

class InvalidRequestException extends InstamojoException {
    public function __construct($errorMessage) {
        parent::__construct (null, null, $errorMessage);
    }
}
```